# MVC Text box validation issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a beginner of .NET coding.

How can we give validation for a text box in which only positive integers are allowed?

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx) attribute on your Model property:

```
[Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
public int YourNumber { get; set; }
```